# I need to get a list of active empty bins using saved search in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I need to get a list of active empty bins using saved search in Netsuite. I tried using the item search and inventory details search. But I didn't get the right solution. Anyone, please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a list of bins where inactive = false, and have one or more items that contain inventory ? This kind of joined search (using two disparate tables of data ) can't be done using a single saved search. Only predetermined (by Netsuite) tables that are logically joined can done on a single search. But there are alternatives :

- Export a list of all Items and their bins (see below) (a) , with a separate search of Bins (b), then use VLOOKUP in (b) to determine the number of items in (a) that are referenced.
- Use SuiteQL ( I haven't tried this ) to create a joined SQL query.
- Use Analytics and create two Datasets ( I haven't tried this either )

On the otherhand, if you would like a list of all items that have a bin reference with no inventory in it, then try creating an Item search with criteria using **Bin On Hand fields...** :  : [image: Bin On Hand fields]

to select **Bin On Hand : On Hand** equal to 0, and the Results set to show **Bin on Hand : Bin Number**